# Finding rows with a unique combination of values (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

This is a bit more complicated that the title lets on, and I'm sure if I could think of a way to better describe it, I could google it better.

I have data that looks like this:

```
SET                     ID    
100301006              1287025
100301006              1287026
100301010              1287027
100301013              1287030
100301011              1287027
```

and I would like to identify and select those rows where each both values in a row have a unique value for the column.  In the example above, I want to grab only the row:

```
100301013              1287030
```

I don't want `SET` `100301006`, since it matches to 2 different records in the ID field (`1287025` and `1287026`).  Similarly, I don't want SET `100301010` since the `ID` record it matches to (`1287027`) can also match another SET (`10030011`).

In some cases there could be more than 2 matches.

I could do this in loops, but that seems like a hack.  I'd love a base R or data.table solution, but I'm not so interested in dplyr (trying to minimize dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `base R`, maybe you can use `ave()` to make it:

```
r <-df[which(with(df,ave(seq(nrow(df)),SET,FUN = length)*ave(seq(nrow(df)),ID,FUN = length)) == 1),]
> r
        SET      ID
4 100301013 1287030
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text="SET                     ID    
100301006              1287025
100301006              1287026
100301010              1287027
100301013              1287030
100301011              1287027",header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded.  I selected @ThomasIsCoding's response, since I find it the most readable.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `duplicated` on each columns independently to create a `list` of logical `vector`s, `Reduce` it to a single vector with `&` and use that to subset the rows of the dataset

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1, function(x) 
         !(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))),]
#     SET      ID
#4 100301013 1287030
```

Or as @chinsoon12 suggested

```
 m1 <- sapply(df1, function(x) !(duplicated(x)| duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))
 df1[rowSums(m1) == ncol(m1),, drop = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SET = c(100301006L, 100301006L, 100301010L, 100301013L, 
100301011L), ID = c(1287025L, 1287026L, 1287027L, 1287030L, 1287027L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick base-R hack:

```r
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
SET                     ID    
100301006              1287025
100301006              1287026
100301010              1287027
100301013              1287030
100301011              1287027")

counts <- sapply(df, function(x) { tb <- table(x); tb[ match(x, names(tb)) ]; })
counts
#           SET ID
# 100301006   2  1
# 100301006   2  1
# 100301010   1  2
# 100301013   1  1
# 100301011   1  2
```

At this point, we have the number of times each element is found in its column ... so we want rows where all counts are 1.

```r
df[ rowSums(counts == 1) == ncol(df), ]
#         SET      ID
# 4 100301013 1287030
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use data.table to select only groups with 1 row, grouping by ID first, then by SET. This is similar to @r2evans method of checking that the counts for ID and SET are both 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, if(.N == 1) .SD, ID][, if(.N == 1) .SD, SET]

#          SET      ID
# 1: 100301013 1287030
```

Or for more than 2 columns

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x[, if(.N == 1) .SD, y], names(df), init = df)
#         ID       SET
# 1: 1287030 100301013
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have a dataframe `df` and want to find unique values of columns: `column1`, `column2`, `column3`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(column1,column2,column3) %>% summarise()
```